# Is it correct to say "see me please"?

Tags: word-choice, politeness

> 'See me please.'
>
> 'Come for meeting.'
>
> 'Let's meet to discuss.'

Which one is the right way to ask someone on Skype to meet in person?

Comment: I would opt for "Let's meet to discuss." as it seems polite.  "See me, please." even though it has "please" seems less polite.  "Come for a meeting." sounds like a command.  Now note how I worded and punctuated—each is different from your original.

Comment: Actually, the teachers in school would write, "Please see me," on my papers. I don't think it's innately rude, but it is certainly imperative.

Comment: "See me, please" would normally be interpreted as a command, as when your superior is about to "call you on the carpet".  "Please see me" (or "Please come for a meeting") would be a more normal request, though the former does have a hint of "command" to it..  "Let's meet and discuss" is a hair more casual, and implies that the two of you should somehow work out to meet relatively briefly (in the hallway, drop by his office, etc) to discuss the matter.

Comment: My professors would sometimes write that on papers/exams when students performed poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether the person is above or below you in seniority (I'm assuming it's a workplace issue?". If the person is below you, I would say "Let's meet to discuss" is good. If the person is above you, I don't find it to be polite enough. In that situation, I would say, "Would you like to schedule a meeting?" or, "May we meet to discuss this?".